# A bookmarklet code to send a same message each time in IM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, bookmarklet, amazon-chime

I am looking to create a bookmarklet were it can send the same message each time.
I am using amazon chime as IM

When a bookmarklet is clicked, it will auto type a message (shown below in image2) and then it must auto hit send button

```
  document.getElementsByClassName("public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr")[0].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = '<span data-text=\"true\">Hey! This is Greg. How may I help you today. Please be advised that this chat is confidential and you agree to terms of XXXX company</span>';
```

[image]

after I click the bookmarklet it must send the message

[image]